# php - rearranging an array into groups

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of filenames:

```
 Array
(
    [2] => 1_1_page2-img1.jpg
    [3] => 1_2_page2-img1-big.jpg
    [4] => 2_1_page2-img1.jpg
    [5] => 2_2_page2-img1-big.jpg
    [6] => 3_1_page2-img1.jpg
    [7] => 4_1_page2-img1.jpg
    [8] => 4_2_page2-img1.jpg
    [9] => 5_2_page2-img1.jpg
)
```

I'm trying to rearrange them so they're grouped together by their first number. I'm guessing I could maybe separate them with a pipe so I could then distinguish them afterwards. Either that or a multidimensional array.

I know I can perform an `explode("_",$filename);` to get the first and second digits before the underscores.

The catch is even though the beginning numbers should always increment, there won't necessarily be 2 files per initial number.

So I'm either trying to make it into the following:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1_1_page2-img1.jpg|1_2_page2-img1-big.jpg
        [1] => 2_1_page2-img1.jpg|2_2_page2-img1-big.jpg
        [2] => 3_1_page2-img1.jpg|
        [3] => 4_1_page2-img1.jpg|4_2_page2-img1.jpg
        [4] => |5_2_page2-img1.jpg
    )
```

Or something a bit tidier perhaps? I just can't work out the `foreach` to put them together.

Or is there an array related command that will put them together easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked it out now based on another post in stackoverflow:

```
foreach ($scanned_directory as $filename){
        $ids = explode("_",$filename);
        $groups[$ids[0]][] = $filename;     
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    ksort($groups);
    print_r($groups);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Displays:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1_1_page2-img1.jpg
            [1] => 1_2_page2-img1-big.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2_1_page2-img1.jpg
            [1] => 2_2_page2-img1-big.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3_1_page2-img1.jpg
            [1] => 3_2_page2-img1-big.jpg
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10_1_page2-img1.jpg
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11_2_page2-img1-big.jpg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to store them in subarrays, as this will be much easier to deal with in the long run; so this would be a possibility, given your array is in `$arr`:

```
$newarr = array ();
while (list($key, $val) = each($arr)) {

    $subarray_index = substr($val, 0, strpos($val, "_"));
    $newarr[$subarray_index][] =  $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$arr = Array(
2 => '1_1_page2-img1.jpg',
3 => '1_2_page2-img1-big.jpg',
4 => '2_1_page2-img1.jpg',
5 => '2_2_page2-img1-big.jpg',
6 => '3_1_page2-img1.jpg',
7 => '4_1_page2-img1.jpg',
8 => '4_2_page2-img1.jpg',
9 => '5_2_page2-img1.jpg'
);


function orderArray($pArr){
    $first = '0';
    $newArr = array();
    foreach($pArr as $val){
      if(strpos($val,$first) !== 0){
         if(substr($val,2,1)==='1'){
           $newArr[]=$val;
         }else{
           $newArr[]='|'.$val;
         }
         $first = substr($val,0,1);
      }else{
         $curIndex = count($newArr) - 1;
         $newArr[$curIndex] = $newArr[$curIndex].'|'.$val;
      }
      return $newArr;
    }

$result = orderArray($arr);

print "number of values: ".count($result)."<br>";
foreach($result as $value){
    print $value."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a nice automated way of doing this, but you could use a simple loop:

```
$array = [];

foreach ($filename as $file) {
    $fields = explode('_', $file);
    $array[$fields[0]][$fields[1]] = $file;
}
```

An example is [located here](http://ideone.com/fEHGEi).